sscanf gave me unexpected result
I am learning C language. This is my code run in linux.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char string[] = "Rudolph is 12 years old";
    char str[20] = {0}
    char i;
    sscanf(string, "%s %*s %d", str, &i);
    printf("%s -> %d\n", str, i);

    return 0;
}

My expected result is:
Rudolph -> 12

But I got the result:
 -> 12

I want to know what happened and why? I try to change char i to int i and then I got the expected result.
But I don't know why I don't get the expected result with char i.

So you already know the answer? A char is one byte and an int probably 4. So when sscanf is storing the value, where does the 3 extra bytes go?! Could that possibly overwrite some other value?

Probably you have warning message for %d and char i. Why you ignore it?

Lie to the compiler (you promised to give sscanf the address of an int (%d) but instead sent the address of a char (&i)) and it will get its revenge!

Not your current bug, but: NEVER ignore the return value of any of the scanf() family of functions.  That's the only way to know whether the conversions succeeded or not.  Also, NEVER use %s conversion without a width specifier in real code - that's just asking for a buffer overflow.

"sscanf gave me unexpected result" seems like a good title for a memoir.

Voting to close this as simple typo since this isn't of any value to future readers and we already have thousands of printf/scanf format string mismatch questions on the site.

%d in scanf functions is for int, not char. Invoking undefined behavior the 3 additional bytes probably will overwrite something else. Address sanitizer finds the problem and compiler warns about the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/YPKv111r9
%hhd is for signed char, %hhu is for unsigned char, when you want to read a number, not a character.
https://godbolt.org/z/o7WYGYfzK

You should use %hhd instead of %d because sscanf treats %d as expecting a 4-byte integer. When using %d, sscanf assumes that the provided memory location is large enough to hold an int (which is typically 4 bytes). This can lead to undefined behavior as sscanf may overwrite adjacent memory. In your specific case, this adjacent memory is likely part of the str array, leading to potential corruption of its contents. Using %hhd ensures that sscanf correctly interprets the target memory location as a char (1 byte).
Here’s the code snippet with the correction:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 char string[] = "Rudolph is 12 years old";
 char str[20] = {0};
 char i;
 sscanf(string, "%s %*s %hhd", str,&i);
 printf("%s -> %d\n", str, i);

 return 0;
}

This change will correctly parse the input string and store the parsed value in a char variable.

"Using %hhd ensures that sscanf correctly" --> makes sense when char is signed, yet not when char is unsigned where "%hhu" is expected.
